# How do I map a resolved promise object in string form onto a button, for example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, callback, components

I understand there are a ton of existing questions that are kind of similar but none of them really were simple enough for my case.

This is the behavior of my promise as of now:

[image]

at least on lines 62 and 63, we can see through the console that the exact and correct values are being found. My goal is to either pass that as a value into `someVar` or otherwise somehow update line 70 with the updated value.

As it stands, my buttons simply render `Object [Promise]` and don't change after the promise has been resolved.

This is basically my first promise function I've ever written and I'm pretty lost to be honest, despite some detailed explanations from others that I think go beyond what I need to know to construct a simple promise for an api call.

full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Highlight} from "react-instantsearch-dom";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Link from 'next/link';
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/styles";
import '../static/default.css';
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch";

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
    **************************
);

const index = searchClient.initIndex("Parks");

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #4496DB 30%, #5df78e 90%)',
        border: 0,
        fontSize: 16,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        width: "100%",
        padding: '0 30px',
    },
    card: {
        minWidth: 275,
    },
    bullet: {
        display: 'inline-block',
        margin: '0 2px',
        transform: 'scale(0.8)',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 14,
    },
    pos: {
        marginBottom: 12,
    },
});

function indexSearch(objId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        index.getObject(objId, ['fullName'], (err, content) => {
            if (content != null){
                resolve(content.fullName);
            }
            else{
                reject(Error());
            }
        });
    });
}

function NewButton({redirectId}){
    const classes = useStyles();
    var someVar = indexSearch(redirectId).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }).catch(function rejected() {console.log('rejected')});
    console.log('after' + someVar);
    return(
        <Link as={`/details/${redirectId}`} href={`/details?objectId=${redirectId}`}>
            <a>
                <button type="button" className={classes.root}>
                    {`Learn more about the ${someVar}`}
                </button>
            </a>
        </Link>
    )
}

class Hit extends React.Component{

    render() {
        const props = this.props;
        return(

            <Card>
                <Paper id="paper" square>
                    <Typography id="title" color="textPrimary" variant="h6">
                        <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-header" attribute="fullName" hit={props.hit}/>
                        <Highlight className="ais-Highlight-state" attribute="states" hit={props.hit}/>
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <Paper square>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="h6">
                        <Highlight attribute="description" hit={props.hit}/>
                    </Typography>
                </Paper>
                <NewButton redirectId={props.hit.objectID}/>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default Hit;
```

Comment: Make function NewButton `async` and `await` the return value of indexSearch. Probably not ideal though to do this within the render lifecycle function though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering a component is synchronous. If you want to do something asynchronous you'll need a state variable in your component. On the first render it will be empty, and you might render some placeholder view such as a loading spinner. You'll then kick off the async stuff, and when it completes you set state causing it to render again.

```
function NewButton({redirectId}){
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    indexSearch(redirectId).then(result => {
      setSomeVar(result);
    }) 
  }, [])

  if (!someVar) {
    return null;
  }

  return(
      <Link as={`/details/${redirectId}`} href={`/details?objectId=${redirectId}`}>
          <a>
              <button type="button" className={classes.root}>
                  {`Learn more about the ${someVar}`}
              </button>
          </a>
      </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh that makes a lot of sense, and ive seen stuff like that before but I always just assumed state was just something out of convenience to toggle variables. ---also, your code worked exactly, so thanks so much. ill really have to eventually get to down learning what every line of code does